# Problem with clipboard

Tags: kubuntu, remote-desktop, clipboard

I am using Kubuntu 16.04. And i mainly use this to connect my remote desktop which is a windows server using rdesktop.

**Issue in detail**.

Now i am facing an issue with copy and paste in my remote section.

The problem is i am not able to copy and paste in my remote desktop. When i copy a text and paste it in remote session, nothing happens.

But i am able to perform this in the same remote desktop when i connect it from LUbuntu 16.04.

Also if i select a text from Kubuntu and paste it in Windows, it is working without any issue. The problem is only when i copy a text from windows and paste it in windows. I am sure that the issue is not with windows.

While i checking the issue in detail i noticed that, when i perform this copy/paste action my clipboard(Klipper) entry is being replaced by blank space, results nothing being pasted.

How can i fix this problem. ?

Any help would be appreciated.